Do I need to resubmit my sitemap when sub-sitemaps change?
I have a main sitemap:

www.example.com/sitemap.xml

This sitemap used to contain sub-sitemaps like this:

www.example.com/sitemap-pt-product-2018-01.xm

Now the structure has changed to:

www.example.com/product-sitemap5.xml.

Considering that the main sitemap hasn't changed and is registered in Google Console, should I re-register the main sitemap or will Google automatically recognize the new sub-sitemaps and remove the old ones? I repeat that the main sitemap is registered in Google Console but it still shows the old sub-sitemaps and hasn't updated to the new sub-sitemaps. Of course, the post/tags links of my site haven't changed; only the structure and names of the sub-sitemaps have changed.
does this change harm ranking of my links?

Yes, It is better to re-submit the updated main sitemap, when changes of sub-sitemaps affect to the main sitemap. It signals to Google Search Console that your website structure has been updated for indexing.

When I resubmitted, it still displayed the same old sitemap, and within a day or two, it automatically recognized the new sitemap. So, resubmitting didn’t make any difference. Thanks!
